# Show availability on load not on click

Tags: jquery

im working on a webshop which is new for me.
We have a link on the product details page which shows the availability of the product instore. The problem is that this info only will shown when the customer clicks on the link. What i want is to show the info when the page loads.

Here is a link to a product:

https://www.bikemore.at/FAHRRAD/STEVENS-Fully-SLedge-27-5-18-anodized-black.htm?SessionId=&a=article&ProdNr=516041167&p=3&rdeocl=1&rdetpl=productpage&rdebox=box1

You see the Info "Vor Ort verfügbar? Jetzt prüfen" which shows the availibility when the customer clicks on it.

Then following happens:

```
    <div id="availability_branches{availability_variantennr}" class="availability_branches mt-s">
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".varop .var-ebene select").change(function() {
        $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").hide();
        $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_open").show();
      });
      $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_open a").click(function() {
        var data, bError;
        bError = false;
        data = { };
        if (VariantenSeite) {
          if (IsGewaehlt()) {
            if ($("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .varnr").text() != document.eingabe.Var.value) {
              data.VariantenNr = document.eingabe.Var.value;
              if ($("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").text() != "")
                $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").text("");
            }
          } else {
            bError = true;
            alert('{s}Bitte wählen Sie zunächst die von Ihnen gewünschte Variante aus!{e}');
          }
        }
        if (!bError) {
          if ($("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").text() == "") {
            $.ajax({
              url: "{URL_AVAILABILITY_BRANCHES}",
              type: "GET",
              data: data,
              cache: false
            })
            .done(function(msg) {
              $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").html(msg);
              if (VariantenSeite)
                $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .varnr").text(data.VariantenNr);
              $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").show();
              $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_open").hide();
              $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_close a").click(function() {
                $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").hide();
                $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_open").show();
              });
            })
          } else {
            $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").show();
            $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_open").hide();
            $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_close a").click(function() {
              $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .availability_branches_content").hide();
              $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_open").show();
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  //--></script>
  <div class="link_open"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="{availability_linktext}" rel="nofollow" class="highlink magenta fontsize12 hover"><strong><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {availability_linktext}</strong></a></div>
  <div class="hide varnr"></div>
  <div class="availability_branches_content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the anonymous function within your click handler to inside the $('document').ready method body.

This is easily achieved by removing the lines:

```
});
      $("#availability_branches{availability_variantennr} .link_open a").click(function() {
```